# app.UseStaticFiles() not working. Index.cshtml loads multiple times

Tags: webpack, .net-core

I have simple .net-core application with webpack.
Webpack generate css and js files for me and store it in wwwroot/dist folder.

It looks like every time css or js file is loaded from dist folder (_Layout.cshtml) it cause index method in HomeController to load once per cs/js request.

My Index.cshtml is empty (for debuting purpose), my _Layout.cshtml looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <base href="~/" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">

        <main id="appContent" class="container-fluid">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="~/dist/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/main.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

In my Startup.cs I have his code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            string cultureCode = options.Value.DefaultRequestCulture.Culture.Name ?? "en-GB";

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{culturecode}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { culturecode = cultureCode, controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                constraints: new { id = new IntRouteConstraint() },
                dataTokens: new { locale = cultureCode });
        });

            app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
            {
                var url = httpContext.Request.Path.ToString();
                if (url.StartsWith("/"))
                {
                    if (cultureCode.ToLower() == "en-us")
                        cultureCode = "en-GB";

                    httpContext.Response.Redirect($"/{cultureCode}/", true);
                    return;
                }
                await next();
            });
        }
```

I tried to configure useStaticFiles method, remove HotModuleReplacement call and changes to routes but with no luck.
As per my understanding by using useStaticFiles all files from wwwroot (dist folder included) should be ignored by routing engin but obviously it doesn't work like that.
Could you see what I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely missing the setting of content root to be your wwwroot. This occurs wherever your program entry point is, and it builds the host. This would also be where you set which class is your startup, usually Main.

You should have something similar to the following:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: In my Program.cs I have public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();  - CreateDefaultBuilder() does this for me.

Comment: Add a . UseContentRoot() to that chained initializer

Comment: I did it but it still doesn't work. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: What happens if you remove your culture middleware? It should be after static files, but just curious

Comment: Still the same without culture middleware.

Comment: Reading the source of the DEV middleware you are adding, it looks like this is how the middleware works, If installed, it proxies all requests before they hit the static file handlers. You can see the middleware here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/7269dbb73f4aa0ebf5ebb8bc07a076ee181851be/src/Middleware/SpaServices/src/Webpack/WebpackDevMiddleware.cs